# How to delete a field inside Firestore document - The field's key contains dots

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a field inside a Firestore document using the KeyPath method.

In other words, I am converting the request body into keyPath string.

Example, converting the below request body:

```
{
    "preferences": {
        "settings":{
            "v1.4.3": [
                "apple"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Into keyPath: `"preferences.settings.v1.4.3"`

and then using this keyPath to delete the path using the following method

```
await userRef.update({
          "preferences.settings.v1.4.3": admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete(),
          lastUpdated: timestamp,
      });
```

This would work normally if the keyPath string doesn't contains dots.
However if it contains it's assuming the `v1` is an object that contains a field with key `4`.

I tried to delete the field using the `set` function as well(see example below) but it didn't seem to work

```
await userRef.set(
          {
              {
               "preferences": {
               "settings":{
               "v1.4.3": null
              }
            }
          },
              lastUpdated: timestamp,
          },
          { merge: true }
       );
```

Please how to solve this issue.

Comment: Does enclosing the field path with backtick ("\`") work, i.e., "\`preferences.settings.v1.4.3\`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` operation interprets dots (`.`) as indications that there are subfields.

Your options to write to a field that has literal dots in its name are to:

- Use `set`/`setDoc`, which does not interpret dots as separators. If you want to update a subset of the document, pass `{ merge: true}` as shown in the second code sample [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_11).
- Use a [`FieldPath` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldPath) for the field name, rather than just the string value.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue, I am trying to delete a field inside a document and not update it. How can I do that using the ```set``` function?

Comment: "it didn't seem to work" is really hard to help with. What happens when you run that code. Note that I didn't tell you to change the value, to `null` - just to change the `update` call to `set`. Also: did you try the `FieldPath` that I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't clarify what happened, what I am trying to do here is to take the request body from the user, and based on that, I want to delete the last nested element inside the object provided. In my example above, I want to delete the ```v1.4.3``` field. I used to convert the object keys into a keyPath string, and use the update method above to delete the field, however that doesn't work anymore because of the dots. I don't think I can use the ```FieldPath``` in my case, neither pass the object as it is in the ```set``` method since I need to pass the value ```.FieldValue.delete()```

Comment: `FieldPath` is used as the **key** in the dictionary, not as the value. Something like `userRef.update({ FieldPath("preferences.settings.v1.4.3"): admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete(), })`, but please look at the reference docs I linked before reporting syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank! it finally worked using the FieldPath.